# iOS webview with repsonsive content scaling to screen not small webview

Tags: ios, webview, popup, responsive-design

We have a native iPad app that relies on a couple of webviews for specific functionality (say login).

The webview renders a page from the website that is responsive. The webview is a popover that is not fullscreen within the app (see attached image).

The problem is: The loaded page renders the page as if it is loaded in the native iPad resolution (1024x768) but we want it to have the size of the popover webview in the app. Is this something you can do with a particular media query or is this something that must be set in the app itself?

[image: Situation, content in webview popover renders to screensize. Not popover size]

Comment: have to check on UIWebView Scale Page to Fit?

Comment: But the page should scale correctly anyways since it's a responsive page. It just gets the resolution of the screen and not the popover.

Comment: hmmm is possible your responsive html have a minimum width? and your web view in less to this minimum width?

Comment: No not really, because this page is also used on the website. Besides that if this solution was possible i'd want to set a maximum width. Because now the content is larger then the popover, not smaller.

Comment: can you post a link? i try to see what happen

Comment: No not really, it's on a restricted development environment. The can only be viewed through testflight and the page is behind ip-restriction and login. But the above image says it all. In the small grey box responsive content is loaded. The content scales to the size of the screen (1024x768) not the size of the small grey webview box.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem is, your web page searching for the device ID and not for the real dimension in PX, I'm sure if you try to stretching a WEB page on your computer the dimension is responsive, but on the devices your `META` searching a device type, you have to try two ways:

1) Uncheck in xcode on `UIWebView` the flag `Scale Page To Fit` it is possible to solve with this.

[image]

2) you have to check your Responsive script on your web page and adding a exactly resolution of your popup in xcode.

Hope this can help you ;)